# Set to fixed: webkit scrollbar thumb size (length/height)

Tags: html, css, webkit, scrollbar

A `ul`'s `height` is dinamically changed from `300px` to `900px`. The ul is set to `overflow-y: scroll` and everytime the `ul`'s height increases, the `scrollbar track` and `scrollbar thumb` get resized together with it.

How can you set the **`scrollbar thumb`** to a **fixed size (height)**, no matter if the `ul` and `scrollbar track` get resized?

I tried adding to `-webkit-scrollbar-thumb`, but without success.

Please view pictures bellow regarding the issue

```
#sidemenu::-webkit-scrollbar
{
    width: 3px;
}

#sidemenu::-webkit-scrollbar-track
{
    background-color: #999;
}

#sidemenu::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb
{
    background-color: #383838;
}
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It might be late for your question, but as I landed to this page accidentally, replying this as it may help others, sourced from this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-webkit-scrollbar)

```
<div class="visible-scrollbar">Thisisaveeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeerylongword</div>
<div class="invisible-scrollbar">Long ul tag goes here or Thisisaveeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeerylongword </div>
<div class="mostly-customized-scrollbar">Thisisaveeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeerylongword<br>
```

```
.visible-scrollbar, .invisible-scrollbar, .mostly-customized-scrollbar {
  display: block;
  width: 10em;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 2em;
}
.invisible-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

/* Demonstrate a "mostly customized" scrollbar
 * (won't be visible otherwise if width/height is specified) */
.mostly-customized-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 5px;
  height: 8px;
  background-color: #aaa; /* or add it to the track */
}
/* Add a thumb */
.mostly-customized-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: #000; 
}
```